# How to get records from two tables with multiple where conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a two tables one is Userregistration and second is user_verificationcode from which i have to get only those record whose email and mobile status are 1.Below are my table structure

Userregistration table

```
........................................
id      fullname   mobile_no       email
.........................................
5      varun         12344567   abc@gmail
6      nitin         12345678   def@gmail
```

user_verificationcode

```
.............................................
id      user_id     codetype      status
............................................
1       5            email           0  
2       5            mobile          1
3       6            email           1  
4       6            mobile          1
```

I want this kind of output

```
........................................
id      fullname   mobile_no       email
.........................................
6       nitin         12345678   def@gmail
```

For this i have used below query but its not working i am not getting how to achieve this.

```
SELECT * FROM Userregistration 
INNER JOIN user_verificationcode ON Userregistration.`id`=user_verificationcode.`user_id` 
where user_verificationcode.`codetype`='email' 
and user_verificationcode.`status`='1' 
and user_verificationcode.`codetype`='mobile' 
and user_verificationcode.`status`='1'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM Userregistration r
INNER JOIN user_verificationcode ve ON r.id = ve.user_id 
                                  and ve.codetype = 'email' 
                                  and ve.status = 1 
INNER JOIN user_verificationcode vm ON r.id = vm.user_id
                                  and  vm.codetype = 'mobile' 
                                  and vm.status = 1
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM Userregistration
where id in
(
    select user_id
    from user_verificationcode 
    group by user_id
    having sum(codetype = 'email' and status = 1) > 0
       and sum(codetype = 'mobile' and status = 1) > 0
)
```

Comment: Thanku so much its work  quite appreciable expert in mysql

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to return only `Userregistration`  fields, since you already know the info contained in `user_verificationcode` table. In this case you can use the following query:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM Userregistration AS t1
JOIN ( 
   SELECT user_id
   FROM user_verificationcode 
   WHERE codetype IN ('mobile', 'email')
   GROUP BY user_id
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT codetype) = 2 AND SUM(status <> 1) = 0 
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You may would like to do something like this

```
SELECT Userregistration.id, Userregistration.fullName, Userregistration.mobile_no,
Userregistration.email FROM Userregistration
INNER JOIN user_verificationcode
ON Userregistration.id=user_verificationcode.user_id
WHERE user_verificationcode.codetype='email' AND user_verificationcode.status = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Userregistration.id, 
       Userregistration.fullName, 
       Userregistration.mobile_no, 
       Userregistration.email 
FROM Userregistration 
INNER JOIN user_verificationcode ON      
       Userregistration.id=user_verificationcode.user_id AND    
       user_verificationcode.status=1
WHERE user_verificationcode.codetype='email' AND        
      user_verificationcode.codetype='mobile'
```